# How to verify web-address with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have a form that looks like that
How to verify if there is a webaddress in the inputfield

```
    <form onsubmit='return formValidation()'>
    <p id="p4"></p>  

        <label>Address:</label>
        <input type='text' id='addr' /><br />

        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value='Suubmit'/>
    </form>
```

my script is

```
 function formValidation(){
    var addr =  document.getElementById('addr');

     if(textAlphanumeric(addr, "* For Address please use numbers and letters *")){
     return true;
     }
     return false;
     }

     function textAlphanumeric(inputtext, alertMsg){
        var alphaExp = /^\d+\s[0-9]\s[a-z]+\s[A-Z]+/;
        if(inputtext.value.match(alphaExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById('p4').innerText = alertMsg; 
            inputtext.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Why it doesnt retrun me anything

Comment: 3 people have downvoted and voted to close, but not one can explain to the OP what they've done wrong?  No wonder people hate Stack Overflow users.  @OP - You need to post all relevant code in the question, so that when external links fail this question is still complete.  Please read **[ask]**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please press edit on your question and place the text of the code into the question. Also take a little time to explain what you are doing and what is going wrong. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO (though, as above, not a particularly welcome welcome so far...) - please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  If you have specific code problems then please try to add a [mcve].

Comment: @Archer you're 100% correct, downvoting is like discouraging people from asking questions or answering questions :-(

Comment: Or veen edit the question maybe guys we are here for the same reasons come on

Comment: I don't see any particular problem with the question. Although I guess you could explain more.

Comment: @ArashKazemi check the edit history - most of the downvotes were when the question was essentially: "here's my code, fix it: link to fiddle"

Comment: @Archer  I couldn't agree more!!!!. I've felt like Devang Bhatt. I understand him. it's his first post on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

if you write onsubmit form, you must use "button" tag.

```js
  function formValidation(){
  
    var addr =  document.getElementById('addr');
  
     if(textAlphanumeric(addr, "* For Address please use numbers and letters *")){
         return true;
     }
     return false;
     }
     
     function textAlphanumeric(inputtext, alertMsg){
     var alphaExp = /^\d+\s[0-9]\s[a-z]+\s[A-Z]+/;
     if(inputtext.value.match(alphaExp)){              
        document.getElementById('p4').innerText = ""; 
      inputtext.focus();
      return true;
     }else{
      document.getElementById('p4').innerText = alertMsg; 
      inputtext.focus();
      return false;
     }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form onsubmit='return formValidation();'>
    <p id="p4"></p>  
            
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input type='text' id='addr' /><br />
        
        <br/>
        <button id="submit" value='Submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
```